# Java Creating Objects at Runtime in a For Loop

Tags: java

I'm trying to create objects within a for loop at runtime.  Here is the (incorrect) code:

```
for(int i=1;i<max;i++){
    Object object(i);
}
```

I'd like it to create max number of Object objects with names object1, object2, etc.  Is there any way to do this?  I have been unable to find anything elsewhere online.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: hMMm yep you can do it

Comment: Learn about arrays and lists.

Comment: What's for? What's next?

Comment: use an array or array list

Comment: This sounds like a school assignment. Please share the objective. At this point even your loop isn't quite correct.

Comment: learn the new keyword

Comment: It's a variation on a school assignment…one I'm just doing for fun.  And yes I can use arrays, and there really is no reason not to.  I'm just curious if there's a way to create objects like this without sticking them all in an array.  It's been pointed out that this wouldn't be very useful, which I hadn't realized.  Will probably just use the array method I'm familiar with

Comment: @user3283171 You can endlessly create objects just by putting `new SomeObject()` in the loop. That would be entirely pointless however. It would constantly create new objects, never to be seen again and java would quitely clear them away. For them to be useful you need to do something with them or at least keep a reference to them (in an array, arraylist or other collection)

Comment: @RichardTingle Yeah, this is what I didn't realize initially…thanks, that's exactly why I'm no longer trying to do this.  Arrays it is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a data structure to store a sequence of objects.  For example, an array could do this:

```
 Fruit banana[] = new Fruit[10];
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
       banana[i] = new Fruit();
 }
```

This creates 10 objects of type Fruit in the banana array, I can access them by calling banana[0] through banana[9]

Answer (score 2):

You could use an array to create multiple objects.

```
public void method(int max) {
    Object[] object = new Object[max];
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        object[i] = new Object();
    }
}
```